# How to cleanly define $().on() selectors

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I am working with an existing jQuery (version 3.2.1) function:

```
$('#example').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', 
   function (e) {
      // do stuff
  });
```

In this case, function(e) will only act if the TD is not the first column in the row.

If I need to add some more not conditions (in what happens to be a table with at least 5 such columns), the function becomes something a little uglier.

In testing it out, I know it works, but there's got to be a better way to do this.

```
$('#example').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child):not(:nth-
    child(2)):not(:nth-child(3))',  
function (e) {
   // do stuff
});
```

Is there a cleaner technique to indicate a set of not conditions in the selector? I was thinking that I could replace the selector string with a function, but I have not seen examples of that in use, even on the [jQuery website](https://jquery.com/).

Comment: `:not(.excludeme)`

Comment: where .excludme is a class?

Comment: well, `excludeme` would be the classname.

Comment: @KevinB -- You should post this as the answer. It's simple and it works perfectly.

Comment: Know this is a late answer, though why not simply use `tbody td:nth-child(n+4)` ... it will start from the 4th item, and much shorter/simpler than exclude the first 3 ... but if to use _exclude_ logic, this will give the same result `tbody td:not(:nth-child(-n+3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lilezek's answer is a good one. If you're looking to shorten your target to single lines, you can define the strings in a variable elsewhere, then pass the variable as the selector to your event handler.

```
var selector_foo = 'tbody td:not(:first-child):not(:nth-
child(2)):not(:nth-child(3))'
...
$('#example').on('click', selector_foo, 
    function (e) {
        // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Both approaches have their strengths and challenges, depending on your ecosystem. I can upvote multiple answers, but alas, I cannot mark more than one as an "answer".

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://api.jquery.com/not/)?

```
$("#example")
  .not(":first-child")
  .not(":nth-child(2)")
  .not(":nth-child(3)")
  .on('click', 
    function (e) {
     // do stuff
   });
```

Disclaimer: I didn't check if this really works.

Comment: I tested @Kevin B's comment and it is actually the simplest. `:not(.excludme)` All I need to do is decorate the specific columns I need and it works perfectly.

Comment: Having an excluding class is a faster solution. But take in mind that you can chain `not` using the code sample here too.